# What does "watch the world walk with you" mean in the sentence "Or stroll up the Cowley Road and watch the world walk with you"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Below is a reading passage in my English exercise book:

> Oxford is most definitely prettier. It is located in the central
>   England. It has a population of about 90,000, of which a large number
>   work in or for the university. This is obviously what the city is
>   famous for but in terms of getting to know the country, what is really
>   of interest is the British Leyland car factory at Cowley. This is
>   huge, employing about 20,000 people, yet, because of the university,
>   it is usually forgotten. Spend a day looking round the works, seeing
>   how they make the cars. Fascinating. Or stroll up the Cowley Road and
>   **watch the world walk with you.**

I don't really understand the meaning of the phrase "**watch the world walk with you**". How can the world walk with somebody?

Could you kindly explain the meaning of this expression?

Comment: **The world** means **everybody**. A similar phrase is **the world and his wife**. But the exercise book (like the second phrase) is out of date: British Leyland was renamed The Rover Group in 1986, and Oxford's population has almost doubled.

Comment: Keep in mind that literature often uses words or phrases that are not common in actual current-day spoken language.  This especially applies to non-fiction books, to "old" books, and (from my point of view in North America) **especially** to _"old British non-fiction books"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard expression is so common in English it even gets its own dictionary entry...

> **watch the world go by** - *to look at people as they go past* <sub>[(Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/watch-the-world-go-by) - also [Macmillan,](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/watch-the-world-go-by) [Longman,...)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/watch-the-world-go-by)</sub>

Normally this refers to something (particularly, *older*) people do *while sitting down* (on a seat in a park, public thoroughfare, etc.). But because OP's example involves the addressee being recommended to *take a stroll* along Cowley Road (a bustling major road running into Oxford city centre High Street) the writer has simply adapted the standard usage in a "one-off" way to suit the specific context.